# Use Angular highchart in angular lib

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, angular-library

I'm creating angular lib and I want to use highcharts-angular + highchart but the problem that I face that while I am using it just get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chart')`

```
DashboardComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chart')
   at Object.get [as chart] (system.src.js:457)
   at HighchartsChartComponent.updateOrCreateChart (highcharts-chart.component.ts:51)
   at HighchartsChartComponent.wrappedUpdateOrCreateChart (highcharts-chart.component.ts:43)
   at HighchartsChartComponent.ngOnChanges (highcharts-chart.component.ts:30)
   at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:23630)
   at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:30761)
   at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:30723)
   at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:31350)
   at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:31314)
   at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (DashboardComponent.html:17)
```

and here the undefined error in highchart lib

```
 updateOrCreateChart() {
   if (this.chart && this.chart.update) {
     this.chart.update(this.options, true, this.oneToOne || false);
   } else {
     this.chart = (this.Highcharts as any)[this.constructorType || 'chart'](
       this.el.nativeElement,
       this.options,
       this.callbackFunction || null
     );

     // emit chart instance on init
     this.chartInstance.emit(this.chart);
   }
 }
```

my HTML Code

```
  <highcharts-chart
                            class="area-chart"
                            [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
                            [options]="chartOptions"
                          ></highcharts-chart>
```

my TS code

```
Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  constructorType = 'chart';
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    exporting: {enabled: false},
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          style: {
            fontWeight: '300'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Time share',
      data: [
        ['Front yard', 10.38],
        ['Closet', 26.33],
        ['Swin pool', 51.03],
        ['Like a boss', 4.77],
        ['Barking', 3.93]
      ]
    }]
  };
```

Comment: Please. [No images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). and also, no links to external resources. You combined both, that's a nice combo. Every time someone does this, I'm amazed at the time spent making a screenshot, uploading the screenshot to a service, getting a link, then linking the image in the question, instead of just... copying and pasting the actual code :|

Comment: @JeremyThille code added

Comment: Thanks! Nothing wrong with this code, as far as I can tell. The problem is probably elsewhere (`this` seems undefined)

Comment: this.chart is not belong to me it's belong to hightchart lib the problem when am trying to use it in angular lib not as angular project

Comment: Uh... What? `this.chart is not belong to me it's belong to hightchart lib`? What do you mean?

Comment: this.chart is part of highchart lib that am use highcharts-chart.component.ts <www.highcharts.com>

Comment: Ha, probably you should use Highcharts for Angular then ([angular-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts))

Comment: using it already to can use it in angular project but not working if i used my component as published lib

Comment: Hi! @OmarTalat are you using https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular ? I don't see too much of what's going on in your application, I have my doubts that you're importing the library Highcharts in the ts file at all.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Yes am using it and it works fine if am going to build as project but if i built it as Lib it fail with these errors !

Comment: Try to recreate a simplified version of your case at the online code editor. That look like not a necessary line at your TS file `constructorType = 'chart';`

Comment: I had the same issue, and the cause was the import statment
I imported ```import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';```   and I was testing with stock sample, which instead I have to import as following  ```import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';```